# Value of Element in Array Seems To Change for C

Tags: c, arrays

So this has got me really stumped. When I run this iterative merge program (to be used in merge sort) below the value of `B[4]` seems to change during the execution of the program and I have no idea why.  Maybe I'm missing something painfully obvious, but this just seems weird.  Here's the print output I get (I initially print array A and B outside of the function. result is also print outside of the function):

```
A: [ 0 89 75 85 13 ]
B: [ 13 12 51 51 29 ]
lenB: 5 lenA: 5
B[4](1) = 29
B[4](2) = 29
B[4](3) = 29
B[4](4) = 0
A value: 0 at A index: 0 A result: 0 at index: 0
B[4](3) = 0
B[4](5) = 0
B value: 13 at B index: 0 B result: 13 at index: 1
B[4](3) = 0
B[4](5) = 0
B value: 12 at B index: 1 B result: 12 at index: 2
B[4](3) = 0
B[4](5) = 0
B value: 51 at B index: 2 B result: 51 at index: 3
B[4](3) = 0
B[4](5) = 0
B value: 51 at B index: 3 B result: 51 at index: 4
B[4](3) = 0
B[4](5) = 0
B value: 0 at B index: 4 B result: 0 at index: 5
A value: 89 at A index: 1 A result: 89 at index: 6
B[4](2) = 0
A value: 75 at A index: 2 A result: 75 at index: 7
B[4](2) = 0
A value: 85 at A index: 3 A result: 85 at index: 8
B[4](2) = 0
A value: 13 at A index: 4 A result: 13 at index: 9
result: [ 0 13 12 51 51 0 89 75 85 13 ]
```

**Code**:

```
    int** merge(int** A, int sizeA, int** B, int sizeB) {
    int i = 0;
    int lenA = sizeA;
    int lenB = sizeB;
    int** result = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * (lenA + lenB));
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    printf("lenB: %d", lenB);
    printf(" lenA: %d\n", lenA);
    printf("B[4](1) = %d\n", B[4]);

    for ( ; a < lenA; ) {
        printf("B[4](2) = %d\n", B[4]);

        for ( ; b < lenB; ) {
            printf("B[4](3) = %d\n", B[4]);

            if (a >= lenA) {
                result[i] = B[b];
                printf("B value: %d", B[b]);
                printf(" at B index: %d ", b);
                printf("B result: %d", result[i]);
                printf(" at index: %d\n", i);
                i += 1;
                b += 1;
            } else {
                if (A[a] < B[b]) {
                    result[i] = A[a];
                    printf("B[4](4) = %d\n", B[4]);
                    printf("A value: %d", A[a]);
                    printf(" at A index: %d ", a);
                    printf("A result: %d", result[i]);
                    printf(" at index: %d\n", i);
                    a += 1;
                    i += 1;
                } else {
                    result[i] = B[b];
                    printf("B[4](5) = %d\n", B[4]);
                    printf("B value: %d", B[b]);
                    printf(" at B index: %d ", b);
                    printf("B result: %d", result[i]);
                    printf(" at index: %d\n", i);
                    b += 1;
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (a < lenA) {
            result[i] = A[a];
            printf("A value: %d", A[a]);
            printf(" at A index: %d ", a);
            printf("A result: %d", result[i]);
            printf(" at index: %d\n", i);
            i += 1;
            a += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: However you have allocated `B` before calling `merge()` isn't quite right, and the allocation of `result()` is located with some overlap of the memory that `B` is pointing to (so when `result[i] = A[a]` is executed, `B[4]` is overwritten).  Note that you also seem to have some confusion about pointers to array of int and pointers to pointers, which might be contributing to the improper allocation of `B`.

Comment: yes I just needed to change all of my int** to int*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using pointers to pointers to `int`s everywhere where you should be using just pointers to `int`s. Change:

```
int** merge(int** A, int sizeA, int** B, int sizeB) {
/*...*/
int** result = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * (lenA + lenB));
```

to:

```
int* merge(int* A, int sizeA, int* B, int sizeB) {
/*...*/
int* result = malloc(sizeof(int) * (lenA + lenB));
```

(Note that since you are writing C, you don't need to cast the return type of `malloc`.)

Also fix any other errors that appear due to these changes. The code as it stands is full of undefined behaviour that will produce seeming random events like the overwriting of B[4] that you have observed.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the type inside the `sizeof()` operator in the malloc call argument should have "one asterisk less than the type of the pointer you expect to be returned". E.g., if you allocate a "pointer to int" (`int*`), you pass "something times `sizeof(int)`". But if you allocate a "pointer to pointer to int", you pass "something times `sizeof(int*)`", etc.

Comment: Great thanks! Not sure what other "undefined behavior" you're talking about as changing all of my int** to --> int* fixed everything. The merge works perfectly now yay!